# Apache Inject a Javascript file when a Specific .HTML file is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, apache, module

On a Website, without modifying the HTML files directly, I want to insert a Javascript File into the HTML when a specific file is loaded.

I'm sure this can be done, but I'm not sure which modules should be used to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page this should allow you to do it with the least amount of hassle

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of solutions here :

1. Use [mod_sed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_sed.html). I am not sure it is the most efficient and maintainable solution though.
2. User [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) So you can intercept requests to your HTML pages and actually call any PHP/Perl/Python script that will return the HTML + your Javascript.